# Android Get current GPS location in WIDGET

Tags: android, google-app-engine, widget, location

Hello I am trying to get the current location of my mobile in an App Widget
The widget receiver works fine. But I am not able to get the longitude and latitude

```
public class MobielTrackingActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1 = "ActionReceiverWidget1";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_LOCATIES = "locaties";
DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

LocationManager locMgr = null;
LocationListener locListener = null;

private double lng = 0;
private double lat = 0;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    // Create a RemoteViews object from  layout
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.main);
    // For button #1

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            if (location != null)
            {
                lng = location.getLongitude();
                lat = location.getLatitude();
            }
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


    Intent mIntent1 = new Intent(context, MobielTrackingActivity.class);
    mIntent1.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1);
    //mIntent1.putExtra("msg", "Uw locatie is opgeslagen met long "+ lng +" en lat " + lat);
    mIntent1.putExtra("msg", "Uw locatie is opgeslagen met " + lat + " " + lng);
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, mIntent1, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_saveLocation,mPendingIntent1);

    // Update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }

    }

    // check, if our Action was called
    // Save current location in database
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1)) {
        String msg = "null";
        try {
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification noty = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Button 1 clicked", System.currentTimeMillis());

        noty.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notice", msg, contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, noty);

        // Add current location to database
        /*SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues newRow = new ContentValues();
        newRow.put("naam", "locatie 1");
        newRow.put("beschrijving", "Wielerwedstrijd door harelbeke");
        newRow.put("lng", 10.254);
        newRow.put("lat", 540.36);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_LOCATIES, null, newRow);
*/
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);

}
}
```

For some reason ly latitude an longitude stays 0.0 and 0.0 what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using only `getLastKnownLocation` which does not turn on the actual GPS receiver. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/